# Removing TextFields in a loop

Tags: actionscript-2

I am trying to create and later remove some Textfields from my stage.

```
for(i=0;i<Chars.length;i++){
    temp = Chars[i] + "_Label";
    _root.createTextField(temp, _root.getNextHighestDepth(), 40, 80+(i*30), 200, 20);
    this[temp].html = true;
    this[temp].vScrollPolicy = false;
    this[temp].selectable = false;
    this[temp].styleSheet=Stat_style;
    this[temp].htmlText = "<h4>" + eval(Mares[i] + ".Name") + "</h4>";      
    temp = Chars[i] + "_Health";
    _root.createTextField(temp, _root.getNextHighestDepth(), 250, 80+(i*30), 200, 20);
    this[temp].html = true;
    this[temp].vScrollPolicy = false;
    this[temp].selectable = false;
    this[temp].styleSheet=Stat_style;
    this[temp].htmlText = "<h4>" + eval(Mares[i] + ".Health") + "</h4>";    
}

stop();


CTRL_Back.onRelease = function() {
    for(i=0;i<Chars.length;i++){
        temp = Chars[i] + "_Label";
        this[temp].removeTextField();
        temp = Chars[i] + "_Health";
        this[temp].removeTextField();   
    }
}
```

The Creating-Part works just fine. But i cant remove them. When I try it out manually by `Char1_Label.removeTextField();` it works but i dont understand why it won't work within my loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem moment is using of `this` inside function definition. In this case it refers to your `CTRL_Back` object not for scope your code written on. So you need to use another reference to your scope. In your case it would be `this._parent` so your remove line should be like this  `this._parent[temp].removeTextField();`